# Sorting Lists By DateTime in Python

Tags: python

just a rather quick question to ask as I have been looking everywhere but haven't seen something that has worked for me I suppose. Suppose I have a list of tuples where:

```
data = (a, b, DateTime, d)
```

I wish to sort the list by dateTime in descending order where the most recent date/time is first. In this case, DateTime is the third element in the list, and I don't seem why my program doesn't sort when I try to sort. Any suggestions on how to sort the hypothetical example above by datetime?

Comment: Is that tuple an *item* of your list, or a representation of the list itself? Can you show your sorting code? It's not entirely clear what you mean to do.

Comment: My apologies, it would be a list of tuples. It is also a representation of a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import datetime

>>> l = [('a', 'b', datetime.datetime.now(), 'd') for _ in xrange(10)]
>>> pprint(l)
[('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 349796), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350127), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350132), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350134), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350137), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350140), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350143), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350145), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350148), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350151), 'd')]

>>> l_desc = sorted(l, key=lambda t: t[2], reverse=True)
>>> pprint(l_desc)
[('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350151), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350148), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350145), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350143), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350140), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350137), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350134), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350132), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350127), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 349796), 'd')]

>>> l_asc = sorted(l_desc, key=lambda t: t[2])
>>> pprint(l_asc)
[('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 349796), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350127), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350132), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350134), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350137), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350140), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350143), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350145), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350148), 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 11, 17, 35, 0, 350151), 'd')]
```